# Nonlinear Hypothesis Testing

Tags: hypothesis-testing, bayesian, nonlinear-regression

A little important background:

I am analyzing an experiment for a physics professor at my college. Each experimental unit is Volume ~ Pulse, with both treated as continuous. Each experimental unit starts with pulse=1, and goes until volume gets close to it's asymptotic value, Volume roughly 1.4 and pulse roughly 20-300. After much stress I was able to discover that the form of the relationship between Volume and Pulse is as follows:

$$Volume = C_0+C_1Pulse^{C_2Pulse} + \epsilon$$

This is interesting because it is a fluid dynamic problem and this has connections to entropy, but that is beside the point. There are two variables which are treatments, Magnet and RPM. Magnet has two levels and RPM has 5 unevenly spaced levels. Some of the combinations has replicates and some do not. Each experimental unit has it's own ID.

The equation for the whole experiment is then the distributional model: (I used this as a guide: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/brms/vignettes/brms_nonlinear.html)

$$
\begin{align}
Volume &= C_0+C_1Pulse^{C_2}+\epsilon \\
   C_0 &\sim ID \\
   C_1 &\sim ID \\
   C_2 &\sim \text{Linear predictor of } RPM*Magnet*Pulse
\end{align}$$

This fits really well.

My question is about hypothesis testing. brms has the handy function 'hypothesis', which does the work, if I specify what I want to test.

I need to tell if there is a difference in the rate of volume loss for RPM and Volume. I am not sure which parameters to test, or what to do. As the interaction is necessary for the model to fit, is it enough to show that the interaction is not equal to zero, thereby showing that both are important? Since I am interested in volume loss, should I have had the first difference of each experimental unit as the response? Should I take the derivative of the fit model above and compare the five levels of RPM and the two levels of Magnet?

Also, is it ok to include the ID as the distributional parameter for $C_1$ and $C_2$, should I have made it also Magnet*RPM?

This will be going into a paper, so things need to be done rigorously, and I want to make sure everything is correct.

Thanks for your help.